# An acceptable way of sorting List

Tags: c#, sorting

I had a problem where I needed to find the largest amount of passengers in multiple cars/vans etc, so I got the totals from each vehicle and added them to a list, I then created this method to sort the list...

```
static List<int> SortList(List<int> tobesorted)
{
    var j = 0;
    int JP = 0;

    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[j]);
    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[JP]);

    for (var i = 0; i < tobesorted.Count-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < tobesorted.Count-1; j++)
        {
            JP = (j + 1);
            value1 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[j]);
            value2 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[JP]);

            if (value2 > value1)
            {
                tobesorted[j] = value2;
                tobesorted[JP] = value1;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
        JP = 0;
    }

    return tobesorted;
}
```

I don't understand is this is acceptable, and if not what methods are? It seems quick enough, I know of sorting algorithms, but haven't ever been forced to use any.

Comment: Why can't you use [sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I can, I just wanted to see if I could do it without?

Comment: I downvoted because I think you COULD put a little more effort in your code/research. Your sort algorithm as is do not sort. CodeReview NORMALY is a place where you provide code that SHOULD be semanthicaly correct or at least as correct as possible.

Comment: Well, I disagree, I posted here as I was looking for the answers that I have gotten; so I think I was right to post here as it's shown me exactly what i asked for. The code does sort, at least it does my end, but that depends on your definition of sorting. 

I typed my question carefully, and I also believed that the code I wrote to be be as correct as possible at my current knowledge level with C#. If I was just posting correct code, what would be the point? I wrote code that I felt happy with, but needed guidance with too. 

"Share code from projects you are working on for peer review."

Comment: Actually I am sorry for that. I wasn't expecting a descending sort

Comment: @BrunoCosta Nobody expects a descending sort. :-)

Answer (score 11):

> I needed to find the largest amount of passengers

If you need just the largest amount, you don't need to sort the whole list (which is slow*), you can instead walk though the list, remember the largest amount found so far and update that as you iterate the list.

LINQ already contains a method that does just that, called [`Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb292667).

---

* Sorting is \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ with a good algorithm, or \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ with a trivial algorithm like the one you used; finding maximum is just \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$.

Comment: Finding max can also be O(1) on a heap but that comes at a cost of O(lg n) in insertion

Comment: @BrunoCosta Yes, a heap makes sense if you need to find max repeatedly in a changing collection, but I don't think that's the case here.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[j]);
> int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(tobesorted[JP]);
> ```

`tobesorted` is a `List<int>`. Hence, all its items are `int`. `int` is a C# language alias / shortcut for `System.Int32` - therefore, the calls to `Convert.ToInt32` are redundant and can be safely removed.

Who's JP? (i.e. use *meaningful* variable names ;)

`List<T>` already has a built-in `Sort` method that should do the trick...

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 is a bad habit of mine, I do it all over my code so I will take note of that. I think that's a remnant of the strings I was originally dealing with!

Have taken them out though, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Mat's Mug is completly right. You shouldn't be calling Convert.ToInt32 in your method since you already know that your list items are of type int. Here is your sort alghorithm, the selecting sort algorithm.

```
static List<int> SortList(List<int> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i++)
    {
        int idxMin = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            if (list[j] < list[idxMin])
            {
               idxMin = j;
            }
        }
        int aux = list[i];
        list[i] = list[idxMin];
        list[idxMin] = aux;
    }

    return list;
}
```

and a test case

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){17,7,3,4,11,15,23,5,10,1};
foreach(int i in SortList(list)){
    Console.Write("{0}, ", i);
}
```

Comment: booooo modifying the input parameters booooo

Comment: it's nothing less than an option, I guess... If you know that the method does that then it's ok. Though I think I would also prefer to do a copy.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I'm just being a peanut gallery

Answer (score 2):

j is initialized every time the inner loop executes. So there is no need to define it in the outer scope.
You can remove j in the outer scope and define the inner loop as

```
for (int j = 0; j < tobesorted.Count-1; j++)
    {
       // ...
    }
```

With this change there is no need to reset the value of j after the completion of inner loop.

Since tobesorted is a reference type so the method definition can be changed to

```
static void SortList(List<int> tobesorted)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you're trying to scratch your ear by reaching around your elbow.  Assuming you have a class representing the Vehicle, something like this:

```
enum VehicleType
{
    None,
    Van,
    Sedan,
    HatchBack,
    PickUp
}
public class Vehicle
{
    public VehicleType Type = VehicleType.None;
    public int MaxPassengers = 0;
    public int NumPassengers = 0;
}
```

And a list of these vehicles:

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = new List<Vehicle>()
{
    new Vehicle{Type =  VehicleType.Van, MaxPassengers = 8, NumPassengers = 5},
    new Vehicle{Type = VehicleType.Sedan, MaxPassengers = 5, NumPassengers = 3},
    new Vehicle{Type = VehicleType.PickUp,MaxPassengers = 3, NumPassengers = 1},
};
```

The highest number of passengers would be:

```
int MostPassengers = vehicles.Max(x => x.NumPassengers);
```

The vehicle list sorted by number of passengers would be something like this:

```
List<Vehicle> SortedByPassengers = vehicles.OrderBy(x => x.NumPassengers);
```

Every vehicle at the bottom of the list with the same number of passengers will be the highest number of passengers.